# What format to send data in over a socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to develop a mobile app, that registered with a Java program through a socket connection. What is the best way to send the data (just a few String's and int's)? I am planning on doing it by just send it as a String in XML form. Is this the best way or is there another standard?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is not much then better send it as a single string delimited by some character (comma or pipe etc). If there is lot of data exchange then a binary format like [Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) or [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/) is better. Other textual options are JSON, XML, YAML.

MY choice is use delimited string as there is no much data.